# how bash is started in gnome terminal

Tags: bash

I found out today that `$-` gives the options with which bash was started.

```
$ echo $-
himHB
```

I would like to know in which file these options to bash were set or which file runs bash with these options.

Comment: @Cyrus I just `grep`ed all those files none of them shows something like `bash <options>`

Comment: Moved the comment from my deleted answer here: you'll need to download Bash's source code to look at them (`apt-get source bash`), also this is on Bash 4.3. Maybe it's badly worded, what I mean is that for job control to be enabled Bash must have been invoked interactively and the operating system must support it, i.e. if bash has not been invoked interactively or the operating system doesn't support it job control won't be enabled.